# How to remove toolbar from website for all users other than Admin in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-website

How can I remove the odoo default toolbar for public users? I mean I don't want any user (except for admin) after login to see the top blue bar which has options of discuss, employees etc..

Please refer the following image :

[image: Website image]

Comment: @czoellner you should make that the answer

Comment: By public users I mean all the users except admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After research of 3 days, I was able to achieve this. Anyone who wants to do this may add the following code in your view.

```xml
<template id="credirect.remove_header" inherit_id="website.user_navbar" name="Remove Header">
<xpath expr="//nav[@id='oe_main_menu_navbar']" position="attributes">
<attribute name="groups">base.group_erp_manager</attribute>
</xpath>
</template>
```